# Do authenticated user stay signed in when i just terminate app without signing out?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am novice in Firebase, and I an currently trying to handle (upon loading app) if user is logged in. 
So according to a book i have to check it like that:

```
if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
      //do smth  
}
```

So as it turns out(if i am not missed something and not wrong) it only checks the last user in Authentication section of a console. I mean if i registered user that way:

```
 Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (User, Error) in
        if Error != nil {
            print(Error)
            return
        }
```

And just terminate my app,then during my check it will see only the last registered user. And after detecting this signed in user and if i sign out then app won't see rest signed in users in the next checking procedure. 
[image]

So it seems like:

1. I ran app then create user several times (create then terminate app and again create then terminate app and back again)
2. Then after step 1 and check if user signed in. Is this last user or 1st user i don't know because i did not found and detail info about it .

   ```
   if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
     //do sign out
     do {
       try Auth.auth().signOut()
     } catch let logoutError {
       print(logoutError)
     }
   ```

   }
3. It finds signed in user then i sing out this user.
4. I terminate app.
5. I run this app again and during initial check of signed in users it does not found any of them.

   ```
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
     navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Logout", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(handleLogout))

   //user is not logged in
   if Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid == nil {
       signOut()
   }
   ```

   }

Why? I mean I did not sign out by myself the rest registered users, and I know upon calling `createUser` func, this createUser func also signs user in.

Maybe app signs out user if i create new? then why i did not found any info about this behavior( Please, if someone have any clue i would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. In step 3 you say that you sign out the user. In that case the behavior in step 5 (it finds no signed in user) seems correct to me.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i sign out only one user not the rest( and according to your answer about Firebase Authentication users stay signed in the users should be signed in, but Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid does not find it why? I did not sign out them(

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't understand. I expanded my answer on how the system works, in hopes that it helps. Beyond that: I hope someone else *does* understand the behavior you describe and can help.

Comment: @N.Khasanov User should not be signed out.  Is the `viewDidLoad:` method is of `rootViewController`? or you initialized its instance in `AppDelegate.m`? I mean have you checked the `viewDidLoad:` function is not calling before your `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` event where you configure the firebase?

Comment: @N.Khasanov You said `i sign out only one user not the rest` the `Auth.auth` maintains only last  and single user so if you signed out that last user you will get nothing. Not getting `not the rest` you don't have more than one user to sign out.

Comment: thank you i got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase Authentication users stay signed in until:

- either your code signs them out explicitly
- or you create another user in the same app on the same device
- or until an event happens that requires them to sign in again (such as a password change)

A single app on a single device can only have a single signed in user. If you sign in (or create) another user on the same device, the previous user will be signed out.